# How to execute onEnter after the onExit api call callback

Tags: angularjs, callback

I call an API on every OnEnter to retrieve the state of my data.
The state of the data is updated on every OnExit by calling a POST on API.

So the test of my state is always late from one state, because the call on the API to retrieve data is called before the save on the State from the onExit.

My question is how to run OnEnter from the OnExit api call callback ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using `ngResourse` or `$http.get` to retrieve the data?

Comment: I use Restangular which use $http.get

Comment: Save the onExit promise and chain the onEnter from it.

Answer (score 0):

Save the onExit promise and chain the onEnter from it.

```
var promise = restangularAPI.post();

promise.then ( function () {
    restangularAPI.get();
});
```

If the post has already completed the get will execute immediately. Otherwise the $q service will wait for the post to complete before executing the get.

Comment: It could be a solution, but for some complexity on my project, I cannot move the restangularAPI.get into restangularAPI.post.
And even if I do this, the data of the next view can be loaded with some delay (due to the response time of the API call) ?